# highlight.js with CKEditor codesnippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, highlight.js

I'm trying to use `highlight.js` with `CKEditor` addon `CodeSnippet`.

I have `CKEditor` working including the `CodeSnippet` addon but my code is not getting detected or colour coded or indented or anything as I would expect.

Reading `highlight.js` it says

> This will find and highlight code inside of pre code tags; it tries
>   to detect the language automatically. If automatic detection doesn’t
>   work for you, you can specify the language in the class attribute:

This is the JavaScript I have in the HTML file to call the `highlight.js`:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/ckeditor/plugins/codesnippet/lib/highlight/highlight.pack.js' %}"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

And this is my `config.js` for `CKEditor`:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {.
    config.toolbarGroups = [
        { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
        { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align' ] },
        { name: 'styles' },
        { name: 'colors' },
        { name: 'insert', groups: [ 'codesnippet'] },
    ];


    config.removeButtons = 'Image,Flash,Table,HorizontalRule,Smiley,SpecialChar,PageBreak,Iframe';

    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';

    config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
};
```

Comment: Things look good in your configuration. Did you check whether highlight.js working with a minimal code, without using CKEditor? [Usage of Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/usage/)

Comment: @HBat I solved it eventually as shown in the answer (which I've just added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'skin': 'bootstrapck',
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            {'name': 'basicstyles', 'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph', 'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList']},
            {'name': 'indent', 'items': ['Indent', 'Outdent']},
            {'name': 'codeSnippet', 'items': ['CodeSnippet',]}
        ],
        'codeSnippet_theme': 'school_book',
        'tabSpaces' : 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
            'codesnippet',
            'widget',
            'dialog',
            ]),
    }
}
```